# How to count the number of values that appear only once (and more than once) in a column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

Lets say I have the following column A:

```
X
Y
X
Z
W
Z
W
```

I want to write 2 formulae, one that counts the number of values that appear exactly once, and one that counts the number of values that appear more than once. So for the above column, the results would be 1 (only Y) and 3 (W, X, Z).

I tried the following formula, but got an error:

```
=FILTER(A:A,COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)>1)
```

How can I do this using Google Sheets? Please note, some column values may be empty and should be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

only once:

```
=FILTER(A:A, COUNTIF(A:A, A:A)=1)
```

[image: 0]

---

more than once:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, COUNTIF(A:A, A:A)>1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: What if I wanted the number instead? So for the first formula, instead of just outputting avb, it would be 3 instead.

Comment: use: `=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(A:A, COUNTIF(A:A, A:A)=1)))`